# Run batch to show result in screen and record in text file

Tags: batch-file

I want to run the a batch to get result to a text file and show in the screen. What should be the correct way to do it ? My script only records the result to a text file but show nothing in screen.

```
netsh int ip show config >%~dp0%computername%.txt
getmac >>%~dp0%computername%.txt
```

Comment: If asynchronous is acceptable, simply adding `type "%~dp0%computername%.txt"` might fit your needs. Else you need an external tool. Google for "tee for windows"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to Stephan's comment, you can try like this :

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Read ip show config And Get Mac
Set "LogFile=%~dp0%computername%.txt"
(
    netsh int ip show config
    getmac
)>"%LogFile%"
If Exist "%LogFile%" Type "%LogFile%"
pause
```

Comment: Thanks. If I do not want to create a text file. What can be done ?